# what does the child class of Equatable pass to the super(Equatable class)?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, equatable

hi I am new with bloc in flutter and I'm trying to understand block timer [In the doc of flutter_bloc](https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/fluttertimertutorial) and I would know what's this constructor class mean

```dart
@immutable
abstract class TimerState extends Equatable {
  final int duration;

//and this list props ??
  TimerState(this.duration, [List props = const []])
      : super([duration]..addAll(props));
}
```

Comment: Could you please define your question more specifically in context to your problem?

Comment: why we add this : ```dart [List props = const []] ```

Comment: and what's this ```dart  super([duration]..addAll(props)); ``` mean

Comment: For anyone seeing this question when using equatable versions > 0.6.x (which you should be in 2020), this no longer applies and has since removed, in favor of requiring overloading a `prop` getter method.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Update: For the new version of Equitable package [>= v 0.6.0](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable/changelog#060) read my [article on Medium](https://medium.com/flutter-community/what-is-equatable-package-in-dart-and-flutter-81bbb62e73b9), for older version or deep understanding read this answer.**

---

When your father gives you and your brother 2 gifts, both gifts are laptops but they are not the same type of laptops; you want to know are both gifts equal or not! So you will compare all aspects that important to you **RAM, SSD, CPU.**

on a paper: `myLaptop: 16G/256G/i5  |   myBrotherLaptop: 8G/512G/i5`

Assuming your brain is using Dart language, and you thought of each gift as an object of this class:

```
class LaptopGiftClass {
  int ram;
  int ssd;
  String cpu;

 // Default constructor
 LaptopGiftClass(this.ram, this.ssd, this.cpu);
}
```

then to compare Equailty of both gifts that created using the class above, Dart and other Object oriented languages e.g Java, C# are expecting you to create(override) these functions, in order to make these languages understand the objects and able to compare any two objects of same class:

```
@override
bool operator ==(Object myBrotherLaptop) =>
    identical(myLaptop, myBrotherLaptop) ||
    myBrotherLaptop is LaptopGiftClass &&
    runtimeType == myBrotherLaptop.runtimeType &&
    name == myBrotherLaptop.name;

@override
int get hashCode => name.hashCode;
```

if these lines scares you off, no one blame you, that's why nice people have created [equatable package](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) for us!

[Equatable package](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) is telling you "leave this scary job for me" But how to delegate the scary code to [equatable package](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable)??!
By doing two things:

1. Make your class extends equatable:
   `dart class LaptopGiftClass extends Equatable {...}`
2. Pass all properties that you need to compare with inside an array to the Equatable(the super/parent class) from moment one, so inside the constructor:

```dart
LaptopGiftClass(this.ram, this.ssd, this.cpu) : super([ram, ssd, cpu]);
```

your final class is:

```dart
class LaptopGiftClass extends Equatable {
  int ram;
  int ssd;
  String cpu;

 // Default constructor
 LaptopGiftClass(this.ram, this.ssd, this.cpu) : super([ram, ssd, cpu]);

}
```

AND YOU ARE DONE! you can now check equality of the two gifts, just create the objects then compare:

```dart
LaptopGiftClass myLaptop = LaptopGiftClass(16,256,'i5');
LaptopGiftClass myBrotherLaptop = LaptopGiftClass(8, 512,'i5');
```

AND JUST BEFORE START COMPARING, your brother saw you, and because he is a gamer, he wants you to add more properties in this equality check: **GPU and Screen_Resolution**! your mother heard that and asked you to add **price** too!

Now you have a list of new props to compare: [GPU, Screen_Resolution, Price].

So because you follow clean code principle, you expected that, and you made the constructor able to get more properties to compare with:

```dart
// This only mean combine both lists
[ram, ssd, cpu]..addAll(myBrotherAndMotherProps)
```

so your final class is:

```dart
class LaptopGiftClass extends Equatable {
  int ram;
  int ssd;
  String cpu;

 // Default constructor
 LaptopGiftClass(
    this.ram, 
    this.ssd, 
    this.cpu, 
    // List of list => because we think "clean code" 
    // and maybe in the future we will send other data; NOT 
    // only an array(list)..
    // so we here sent the extra props we need to
    // compare 'myBrotherAndMotherProps', and 
    // as sometime brother and mother will not ask you 
    // to add props to compare, you give it a default value 
    // as empty "const []", why const here??! just for better 
    // performance as we are so soooo Professional!!

    [ List myBrotherAndMotherProps = const [] ],

 ) : super([ram, ssd, cpu]..addAll(myBrotherAndMotherProps));

 // WHY TO PASS FROM INSIDE THE CONSTRUCTOR? 
 // because Equatable needs them (required) 
 // and not at anytime but immediately inside the 
 // constructor of itself, so we made this 
 // chaining(constructor pass to another constructor)..
}
```

So it's obvious that the essintial properties are [RAM, SSD, CPU], but anything extra will be take into consideration too as we made the implementation clean, flexible, and scalable.

before adding this flexible code `List<Object> get props => [RAM, SSD, CPU]..addAll(myBrotherAndMotherProps);` these used to be EQUAL!!:

```dart
// Note first 3 are equal [ram, ssd, cpu]:
LaptopGiftClass myLaptop = LaptopGiftClass(16,256,'i5', ['Nvidia', 1080, '1200$']);
LaptopGiftClass myBrotherLaptop = LaptopGiftClass(16, 256,'i5', ['Intel HD', 720, '900$']);

myLaptop == myBrotherLaptop; // True without ..addAll(myBrotherAndMotherProps);
myLaptop == myBrotherLaptop; // False with ..addAll(myBrotherAndMotherProps);
```

---

Same happening with TimerState:

```
@immutable
abstract class TimerState extends Equatable {
  final int duration;

  TimerState(this.duration, [List props = const []])
      : super([duration]..addAll(props));
}
```

`TimerState` is implemented just like `LaptopGiftClass` above(last implementation).
you can send `props` to it using the constructor:

```
TimerState(this.duration, [List props = const []])
      : super([duration]..addAll(props));
```

so `TimerState` will pass props's list to its parent(super/ the Equatable/ what extended..) in this line like this:
 `: super([duration]..addAll(props));`

and in this timer example; `duration` is the basic prop, just like `[RAM, SSD, CPU]` to LaptopGiftClass.

and the hierarchy will be like this:

```dart
// Inside class Paused extends TimerState {...}
Paused(int duration) : super(duration); // super is TimerState

// then Inside abstract class TimerState extends Equatable {..}
TimerState(this.duration, [List props = const []])
      : super([duration]..addAll(props)); // super is Equatable

// Then Equatable will get props and deal with it for you...
```

Comment: Quite Nice Explanation.

Comment: that's some solid understanding there! nice one @Jehad Nasser :)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial use `equatable: ^0.2.0`, in this version when you want to override the `hashcode` and `==` operator you need to pass a `List` of the properties to the `super` constructor. Check out the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable/versions/0.2.0).

Whit this in mind, he create a optional parameter called `props`, and pass to the super constructor a `List` that contains `duration` and all elements of the `props` parameter.

```dart
abstract class TimerState extends Equatable {
  final int duration;

  TimerState(this.duration, [List props = const []])
      : super([duration]..addAll(props));
}
```

In this way the class that extends `TimerState` can use the `props` optional parameter to pass other properties, and this properties would be added to the `List` that is passed to the `super` constructor of `TimerState` for use `Equatable` correctly.

So if you need a state that have other properties you need to do this:

```dart
class OtherTimerState extends TimerState {
  final int otherProperty1;
  final int otherProperty2;

  OtherTimerState(int duration, this.otherProperty1, this.otherProperty2)
      : super(duration, [otherProperty1, otherProperty2]);
}
```